# django import i couldnt create main file into my project file

Tags: python

```
C:\Users\sushant dhore>cd C:\Users\sushant dhore\Desktop\myside

C:\Users\sushant dhore\Desktop\myside> py -3.7.3 manage.py startapp main
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\sushant dhore\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe -3.7.3 manage.py startapp main'
```

Comment: command should be like this `python manage.py startapp main`.

Comment: still its not working same error

Comment: what's the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
python manage.py startapp main
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/